# Differentiate apposition from list

Tags: lists, appositives

In the following sentence, I can only distinguish by *knowing* whether this is an apposition, i.e. the basic principles of material supply are kitting and line stocking, or whether the whole thing is a list, i.e. "this" applies to the list that follows.

Is there a better way to make this clear right away here? My goal is apposition, so the basic principles of MS are kitting and LS. Would the use of a semicolon be appropriate here, for example? Or is the typical way to use i.e.?

> There are basic principles of material supply, kitting and
> line stocking.

Comment: Semicolon, no; a colon or a dash, perhaps.

Comment: @user405662 and for sure?

Comment: *This applies to the basic principles of material supply, which are kitting and line stocking*.  or *...basic principles of material supply, that is, kitting and line stocking*.  Or, *...material supply, i.e., kitting and line stocking.*

Comment: What does MV stand for?

Comment: @Billj Should be MS (material supply) instead of MaterialVersorgung, which is German.

Comment: For the other sense/s: 'This applies to the basic principles of material supply, kitting, and line stocking.' shows an essential Oxford comma usage to force the 3-member list. But whether the first element is 'the basic principles of material supply' or 'material supply' is still in need of disambiguation by some means (rewriting or knowledge of the processes involved). Some would say that omitting the Oxford comma should force the 2-member list, but in practice this is not wise to assume.

Comment: To concentrate on some of your questions: Yes, this is an appropriate use of "i.e." Don't confuse with "e.g." And a semicolon doesn't work because what follows isn't an independent clause. A colon would, but @JackO'Flaherty's examples of just adding a few words are more natural.

Comment: I generally like these answers, but none both use apposition, which OP said was his goal (I don't know why), and resolve @EdwinAshworth's concern that the appositives' referent could be either "basic principles of material supply" or "material supply". The only solution I can think of is to reverse the elements: "This applies to kitting and line stocking, the basic principles of material supply."

Comment: Presumably the main point of this sentence is to state that "this" applies to both primary types of MS.  But at the same time, you seem to be trying to use this sentence to introduce the two primary types of MS.  Please don't try to mush both of these purposes into one sentence. Note that we can't possibly help you rewrite this sentence because we don't have the context.  But in general, you can make things clearer with the word "namely," e.g. *I like both types of pie served traditionally at Thanksgiving, namely, apple and pumpkin.* / Voting to close ("proofreading").

Comment: I was asking a general question about "concise appositions", general because it is a common "problem" encountered when one often has to deal with "basic principles", it has not a thing to do with proofreading. I changed the sentence so the actual problem becomes clearer. Thanks for the suggestions.